# Using Prism 6 Event Aggregator between view models with an object as the payload

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, eventaggregator

Hi I'm hoping one of you could help me with some syntax.

So I'm following this example https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/591221/Simple-EventAggregator-in-WPF-PRISM on using Prism Event Aggregator to send messages from one ViewModel to another.

The following code works great when publishing a single string as the payload.

```
internal class OrderSelectedEvent_SS : PubSubEvent<string>
{
    private static readonly EventAggregator _eventAggregator;
    private static readonly OrderSelectedEvent_SS _event;

    static OrderSelectedEvent_SS()
    {
        _eventAggregator = new EventAggregator();
        _event = _eventAggregator.GetEvent<OrderSelectedEvent_SS>();
    }

    public static OrderSelectedEvent_SS Instance
    {
        get { return _event; }
    }
}
```

Publisher (In ViewModel1):

```
OrderSelectedEvent_SS.Instance.Publish(_strCurrentOrder);
```

Subscriber (In ViewModel2:

```
OrderSelectedEvent_SS.Instance.Subscribe(OrderSelectedEventHandler_SS);
private void OrderSelectedEventHandler_SS(string strSelectedOrder)
    {
        CurrentOrder = strSelectedOrder;
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is modify to accept an object (a class with multiple strings) as the payload.
Here's what I have so far:

```
internal class OrderSelectedEvent : PubSubEvent<object>
{
    private static readonly EventAggregator _eventAggregator;
    private static readonly OrderSelectedEvent _event;
    static OrderSelectedEvent()
    {
        _eventAggregator = new EventAggregator();
        _event = _eventAggregator.GetEvent<OrderSelectedEvent>();
    }

    public static OrderSelectedEvent Instance
    {
        get { return _event; }
    }

    public class OrderSelectedPayload
    {
        public string SelectedOrder { get; set; }
        public string SelectedE32 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Publisher (In ViewModel1):

```
OrderSelectedEvent.OrderSelectedPayload ospl = new OrderSelectedEvent.OrderSelectedPayload();
ospl.SelectedOrder = _strCurrentOrder;
ospl.SelectedE32 = _strCurrentE32JobNumber;
OrderSelectedEvent.Instance.Publish(ospl);
```

Subscriber (In ViewModel2:

```
OrderSelectedEvent.Instance.Subscribe(OrderSelectedEventHandler);
```

I'm getting an error here on the subsriber: **ERROR: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Action'**** and I can't seem to figure out what I need to do.

```
private void OrderSelectedEventHandler(OrderSelectedEvent.OrderSelectedPayload ospl)
{
    CurrentOrder = ospl.SelectedOrder;
    CurrentE32JobNumber = ospl.SelectedE32;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance you can provide.

Comment: What version of Prism are you trying this with? The most recent version is 6.2.

Comment: Okay, that article is offering a solution that is, well, junk. With that you are `new`'ing up an `EventAggregator` in the `PubSubEvent` ctor, rather than getting of from an IOC container. You need to look here (http://prismlibrary.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WPF/09-Communication/) to see more about event aggregation with Prism. Un-bookmark that Code Project example, and forget you ever saw it.

Comment: I'm using the latest Prism 6.2. I'll look into that solution. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @R.Richards is absolutely correct! That solution is complete junk. It is the worst implementation of the event aggregator I think I have ever seen.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will find a better implementation.

Comment: Prism docs have moved here: http://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/.  The communication page is now here: http://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/wpf/Communication.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is simple: You are defining the event to pass an `object` as payload, then trying to use a specific class as payload instead. To fix this, change

```
internal class OrderSelectedEvent : PubSubEvent<object>
```

To:

```
internal class OrderSelectedEvent : PubSubEvent<OrderSelectedPayload>
```

Alternatively, you could change your handler signature to match the expected parameters of the event:

```
private void OrderSelectedEventHandler(OrderSelectedEvent.OrderSelectedPayload ospl)
```

To:

```
private void OrderSelectedEventHandler(object ospl)
```

Comment: Thank you! This solves my specific question. I am, however, going to take the advice from the comments above and find a better implementation. I really appreciate everyone's comments.

Comment: That's probably for the best.  Good luck!