# how to call the method in another viewmodel using event aggregator in wpf

Tags: wpf, prism, eventaggregator

I have two Views and two ViewModels with names Part and partItem. I have one private method in PartViewModel and I just need to call that method from PartitemViewModel with EventAggregator.

Comment: Can you show your code? It is helpful to others to see what you have already attempted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Prism 6 Event Aggregator between view models with an object as the payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42451146/using-prism-6-event-aggregator-between-view-models-with-an-object-as-the-payload)

Answer (score 0):

Either move the method in a service available to both view models or create an event and subscribe to it in `PartViewModel` and publish it from `PartItemViewModel`.

The event variant has the drawback that you cannot easily return anything. Also consider that if you have multiple instances of `PartViewModel`, all of them will react to the event.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have misunderstood what an event aggregator is all about: Loose coupling between the publisher and the subscriber.

You don't ever call a method of another view model using an event aggregator.

The publisher publishes an event and don't know anything about any of the subscribers that *may* have subscribed to receive messages of the same type.

The publisher and the subscriber only knows about the event aggregator but they don't know anything about each other. That's the whole point of using an event aggregator in the first place.

Please refer to the following link for more information: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/02/28/using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models/